# How to create a PostgreSQL pivot table that pivots multiple columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot-table, crosstab

I have been been exploring the `crosstab()` function in PostgreSQL's `tablefunc` [extension module](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/tablefunc.html), as a way of producing pivot tables.

It's great, but seems suitable for only the most basic of use cases.  It generally supports only THREE columns of input:

1. A column of values that remain unchanged, as row labels
2. A column of values that are pivoted, to become new column names
3. A column of values that become the values for their respective new pivot columns

Basically taking this:

```
+------+----------+-------+
| ITEM |  STATUS  | COUNT |
+------+----------+-------+
| foo  | active   |    12 |
| foo  | inactive |    17 |
| bar  | active   |    20 |
| bar  | inactive |     4 |
+------+----------+-------+
```

... and producing this:

```
+------+--------+--------+----------+
| ITEM | STATUS | ACTIVE | INACTIVE |
+------+--------+--------+----------+
| foo  | active |     12 |       17 |
| bar  | active |     20 |        4 |
+------+--------+--------+----------+
```

But what about more complex use cases?  What if you have:

1. MULTIPLE input columns that you would like to remain as-is in the output?
2. MULTIPLE input columns that you would like to pivot into new columns?

As in the example below:

```
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------+-------+------------------+
| SYSTEM |  MICROSERVICE   |  MONTH  | METRIC | VALUE | CONFIDENCE_LEVEL |
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------+-------+------------------+
| batch  | batch-processor | 2019-01 | uptime |    99 |                2 |
| batch  | batch-processor | 2019-01 | lag    |    20 |                1 |
| batch  | batch-processor | 2019-02 | uptime |    97 |                2 |
| batch  | batch-processor | 2019-02 | lag    |    35 |                2 |
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------+-------+------------------+
```

Where the first THREE columns should carry over as-is for each row (no grouping or aggregation).  And the `metric` column has TWO associated columns (i.e. `value` and `confidence_level`) to pivot for it?

```
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+
| SYSTEM |  MICROSERVICE   |  MONTH  | UPTIME_VALUE | UPTIME_CONFIDENCE | LAG_VALUE | LAG_CONFIDENCE |
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+
| batch  | batch-processor | 2019-01 |           99 |                 2 |        20 |              1 |
| batch  | batch-processor | 2019-02 |           97 |                 2 |        35 |              2 |
+--------+-----------------+---------+--------------+-------------------+-----------+----------------+
```

I'm not sure if this still fits the strict definition of "pivot table".  But is such a result possible with `crosstab()`, or any other readily-available PostgreSQL function?  If not, then how could it be produced with a custom PL/pgSQL function?  Thanks!

Comment: SQL is not designed to do something like that. This is much better done in your front end code. Or maybe aggregate the dynamic columns into a single JSON value,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using conditonal aggregation

```
select system,MICROSERVICE , MONTH,
max(case when METRIC='uptime' then VALUE end) as uptime_value,
max(case when METRIC='uptime' then CONFIDENCE_LEVEL end) as uptime_confidence,
max(case when METRIC='lag' then VALUE end) as lag_value,
max(case when METRIC='lag' then CONFIDENCE_LEVEL end) as lag_confidence
from tablename
group by system,MICROSERVICE , MONTH
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you!  I was so hung up on the term "pivot table" (which I'm not 100% sure this is when you have multiple "pivots").  I should have taken a step back and thought about ways to achieve the actual result, without getting hung up on terminology that steers toward a certain approach.

Answer (score 0):

A different approach (that I have used) is to write the data out to a file, use a separate utility to crosstab it in the desired format, and import the result into a new table.